# spi overlay driver don't run due to shared pin11

Tags: pi-3, gpio, spi

I'm trying to run old FLIR Lepton driver on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v1.2 (2015).
FLIR SW driver here: https://www.flir.eu/developer/lepton-integration/lepton-integration-raspberry-pi/.
PDF guide here: https://flir.netx.net/file/asset/41693/original/attachment
SW package here: https://novacoast-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/p/slewis/EV7LFwCXzWpMsHh_k7NTSXcBOZ8JRZdCSpI4sxeVQFD62Q?download=1

After fixing the incompatibilities of the driver with linux kernel, seems that there are two active SPI functions fighting for the same SPI CLK line:

```
    $dmesg
    ...
    [   11.441642] pinctrl-bcm2835 3f200000.gpio: pin gpio11 already requested by 3f204000.spi; cannot claim for spi0.0
    [   11.441679] pinctrl-bcm2835 3f200000.gpio: pin-11 (spi0.0) status -22
    [   11.441701] pinctrl-bcm2835 3f200000.gpio: could not request pin 11 (gpio11) from group gpio11  on device pinctrl-bcm2835
    [   11.441722] spidev spi0.0: Error applying setting, reverse things back
    ...
```

/boot/config.txt:

```
$cat /boot/config.txt
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18
dtoverlay=flir-lepton-00A0

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

kernel=kernel7.img

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]
```

Normally if I don't install the overlay, there are two SPIs visible in /dev - spidev0.0 and spidev0.1. However, when trying to apply the overlay, ls -l /dev/*spi* returns:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 0 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/spidev0.1
```

The target of the overall driver is to emulate video source (probably /dev/video0), but having the currently described issue, I see only the default video dev's:

```
$ls -l /dev/vid*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  0 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video10
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  1 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video11
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 10 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video12
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  2 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video13
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  3 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video14
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  4 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video15
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  5 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video16
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 11 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video18
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  6 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video20
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  7 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video21
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  8 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video22
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  9 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video23
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 12 Feb 19 07:25 /dev/video31
```

Last but not least - the flir-lepton-00A0.dts file describing the overlay:

```
$cat RaspberryPi/lepton_module/flir-lepton-00A0.dts
// #include <dt-bindings/pinctrl/am33xx.h>
// #include <dt-bindings/interrupt-controller/irq.h>

/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/* Wired up as follows on the Raspberry Pi 3:
        CS -> BCM/GPIO 8 (CEO)
        MOSI -> BCM/GPIO 10 (MOSI)
        MISO -> BCM/GPIO 9 (MISO)
        CLK -> BCM/GPIO 11 (SCLK)
        GND -> GROUND
        VIN -> POWER 3v3
        SDA -> BCM/GPIO 2 (SDA)
        SCL -> BCM/GPIO 3 (SCL)
        VSYNC ->
*/

/ {
        compatible = "brcm,bcm2837", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";

        version = "00A0";

        /* state the resources this cape uses */
        exclusive-use =
                /* the pin header uses */
                // SPI0_CS0
                "GPIO8",
                // SPI0_D0 MISO
                "GPIO10",
                // SPI0_SCLK
                "GPIO11",
                // VSYNC
                "GPIO17",


                /* the hardware ip uses */
                "spidev0";

        // Disables SPIDEV
        fragment@0 {
                target = <&spidev0>;
                __overlay__ {
                        status = "okay";

                        spidev@0 {
                                status = "disabled";
                        };

                        spidev@1 {
                                status = "disabled";
                        };
                };
        };

        /* So this fragment is an overlay for the current GPIO settings, which
           will adjust the default values when applied. Another fragment is
           needed to apply this overlay */
        fragment@1 {
                // Configuration for the GPIO pin controller
                target = <&gpio>;
                __overlay__ {
                        /* default state has all gpios released and mode set to uart1 */
                        rpi_spi_pins: rpi_spi_pins {
                                brcm,pins = <11 9 8 17>; // clk, d0, cs0, VSYNC
                                brcm,function = <4 4 1 0>; // <SPI SPI OUTPUT INPUT>
                                brcm,pull = <1 1 2 1>; // 2 = PULLUP, 1  = PULLDOWN
                        };
                };
        };

        /* Overlays the GPIO fragment and contains Lepton-specific configuration */
        fragment@2 {
                target = <&spidev0>;
                __overlay__ {
                        /* AVOIDS DTC WARNING */
                        #address-cells = <1>;
                        #size-cells = <0>;

                        status = "okay";
                        pinctrl-names = "default";
                        pinctrl-0 = <&rpi_spi_pins>;

                        lepton2 {
                                #address-cells = <1>;
                                #size-cells = <0>;

                                compatible = "flir,lepton2";

                                /* SPI setup
                                 *
                                 * lepton SPI mode 3: CPHA = 1, CPOL = 1
                                 * p. 50 Lepton with Radiometry Datasheet (500-0736-01-09 rev 110)
                                 */
                                reg = <0>;
                                spi-max-frequency = <24000000>;
                                spi-cpha;
                                spi-cpol;

                                /* VSYNC setup */
                                interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
                                interrupts = <17 0x00000001>;
                        };
                };
        };
};
```

I tried to enable spi0 overlay having only 1 CS line (spi0-1cs). Tried also with spi0-0cs - each time on startup the error is the same.
Obviously I'm not expert in linux device drivers and in general I don't get which settings are colliding and why. Even though low levels are fun, that takes too much time. Please help to understand and fix.

Comment: What goes wrong if you comment out `dtparam=spi=on` and reboot?

Comment: few stuff happen when dtparam=spi=on is commented:
`$ dmesg` --> the warning for gpio collision is gone.
`$ ls -l /dev/*spi*` --> no spi device in the list
`$ ls -l /dev/*vid*` --> still the same amount of video devices, but no video0

If I run `sudo depmod -a` and then `sudo modprobe lepton`, then lepton is loaded
`[  125.920589] lepton: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.`
but still no video0 device.
I don't get why the SPI has to be disabled, according to the pdf guide it should be ON.

Comment: Please edit that information into your question (people should not have to read comments).